Terraform unable to create helm_resource, even though EKS Cluster is publicly and privately accessible, and on the same VPC and private subnet
I create an eks cluster like so:
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.11"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "~> 2.11.0"
    }
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "~> 1.14.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_poc" {
  name     = "${local.cluster_name}"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eiam_role.arn
  
  
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = var.private_subnets
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_cluster_AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
  ]
}


And an accompany helm resource:
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_id
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
      args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks_cluster.cluster_id]
      command     = "aws"
    }
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller" {
  name = "aws-load-balancer-controller"

  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts/"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  namespace  = "kube-system"

  set {
    name = "image.repository"
    value = "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = aws_iam_role.aws_load_balancer_controller.arn
  }

    set {
    name  = "vpcId"
    value = module.eks_cluster.cluster.vpc_config[0].vpc_id
  }  

  set {
    name  = "region"
    value = data.aws_region.current.id
  }    

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = module.eks_cluster.cluster_id
  }

  set {
    name  = "controllerConfig.featureGates.SubnetsClusterTagCheck"
    value = "false"
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.eks_cluster.node_group,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_load_balancer_controller_attach
  ]
}

But I'm getting this error in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline:
...
module.eks_cluster.aws_eks_cluster.eks_poc: Still creating... [7m30s elapsed]
module.eks_cluster.aws_eks_cluster.eks_poc: Still creating... [7m40s elapsed]
module.eks_cluster.aws_eks_cluster.eks_poc: Still creating... [7m50s elapsed]
module.eks_cluster.aws_eks_cluster.eks_poc: Creation complete after 7m53s [id=esn-526-pipelines-eks_cluster_poc]

...

helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller: Creating...
helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://xxx.yl4.eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/version": dial tcp 100.80.18.109:443: i/o timeout
│ 
│   with helm_release.aws-load-balancer-controller,
│   on helm.tf line 46, in resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller":
│   46: resource "helm_release" "aws-load-balancer-controller" {
│ 
╵

I'm not sure why this is.
The EKS cluster itself has 3 private subnets, and the ec2 instance which acts as my gitlab runner runs has one of these private subnets as its subnet. And both the cluster and the runner ec2 instance sit on the same VPC.
Please help if you can!
Initially thought maybe turning endpoint_public_access to true as well as endpoint_private_access to true would get past this issue, but it hasn't.. however - I'm not sure how it would have, considering the runner is on a private subnet.

The security group for the subnet where the elastic network interface reside (for the EKS control plane); must allow connection from your runner.
